# How to decode a base64 image and write to file using PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, base64, image-uploading

I'm currently attempting to write an image to a folder on my webserver, something is being written, but it is not an image. My firedebugger is also giving me an error

```
PHP Warning: imagecreatefromstring() : Data is not in a recognized form
```

The file that is written has the correct name, but is not openable by text or image programs. When angularJS uploads an image the $_POST data that php is attempting to retrieve begins with this.

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/
```

PHP

```
<?php

ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "100M"); // to avoid anyone can send a gigabyte of file
ini_set("post_max_size", "101M"); // and break down the server...

define("MAX_IMGSIZE", 500000);
define("UPLOAD_DIR", (realpath("../uploads")).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require_once("functions.php");

// define("XHR", isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) ? strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ? true : false : false);
// if(XHR)
// {
//  echo "yes";
// }

$errors = [];
if(!empty($_POST["img"]) && !empty($_POST["imgsize"]) && !empty($_POST["imgname"]) && !empty($_POST["filter"]))
{

    //      __________  ____  __  ___
    //     / ____/ __ \/ __ \/  |/  /
    //    / /_  / / / / /_/ / /|_/ / 
    //   / __/ / /_/ / _, _/ /  / /  
    //  /_/    \____/_/ |_/_/  /_/   
    //                               

    // or extract($_POST);
    $img     = $_POST["img"];
    $imgsize = intval($_POST["imgsize"]);
    $imgname = htmlentities(trim($_POST["imgname"]));
    $imgname = array_shift(explode('.', $imgname));
    $filter  = htmlentities($_POST["filter"]);

    if(strlen($imgname) == 0) // if image uploaded with empty name
        $errors[] = ["Error 54", "Image filename is empty"];

    if(check_base64_image($img))
        $errors[] = "Uploaded image is not valid!";

    if($imgsize >= MAX_IMGSIZE)
        $errors[] = sprintf("Uploaded image is too large! Maximum wieght is : %s Kb", MAX_IMGSIZE/1000);



    if(is_dir(UPLOAD_DIR)) // if upload directory exists
    {
        if(file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIR."${imgname}_".time(), base64_decode($img)))
        {
            //     ____  ____  ______
            //    / __ \/ __ \/ ____/
            //   / / / / /_/ / /     
            //  / /_/ / _, _/ /___   
            //  \____/_/ |_|\____/   
            //                       
            // ALL SOUNDS GOOD --> ORC BEGIN

            if(exec("binary path... arg0 arg1", $o))
            {

                // rest of process

            }else
                $errors[] = ["Error 12", "Binary failed"];
        }else
            $errors[] = ["Error 32", "Cannot write image file"];

    }else
        $errors[] = ["Error 42", "Upload dir does not exists"];

}else
    $errors[] = "Filter and Image are required, please complete the form!";


//      __________  ____  ____  ____  _____
//     / ____/ __ \/ __ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/
//    / __/ / /_/ / /_/ / / / / /_/ /\__ \ 
//   / /___/ _, _/ _, _/ /_/ / _, _/___/ / 
//  /_____/_/ |_/_/ |_|\____/_/ |_|/____/  
//                                         

if(count($errors)) // check first system error, and shift them
{
    foreach($errors as $ie => $e)
    {
        if(is_array($e)) // system error, do not show in front for security
        {
            error_log($e[0]);
            unset($errors[$ie]);
        }
    }

    if(count($errors)) // if staying errors, inform the user
        exit(json_encode($errors));
}
?>


<!-- 
if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])){
  $errors= array();        
  $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];   
  $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");        
  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
    $errors[]="image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }
  if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
  }               
  if(empty($errors)==true){
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../uploads/".$file_name);
    echo " uploaded file: " . "images/" . $file_name;
  }else{
    print_r($errors);
  }
}

/*else{
  $errors= array();
  $errors[]="No image found";
  print_r($errors);
  }*/
 -->
<!-- function printArray($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo "$key => $value";
    if(is_array($value)){
      printArray($value);
    }
  }
} -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the header information from the angularJS was the problem. To fix this I removed

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,
```

before the actual base64 string that is the image in the post data. To fix this I added a function that does the following.

```
function headerRemove($img){
    $pos = strpos($img, ",",11);
    $img = substr($img, $pos, strlen($img));

    return img;

}
```

In angularJS I found that a "," was used before the base64 string of the actual image began. The index 11 position was used because the proper place to start looking for the 2nd "," depends on whether or not the image type is a png or jpeg.